# $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{\alpha}e^{|\log x|^{1/2}}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given any $\alpha > 0$, I need to show that for $ x \in [0,\infty)$
 \begin{equation}
     \lim_{x\to 0} x^{\alpha}e^{|\log x|^{1/2}}=0
\end{equation}

I have tried using L'Hospital's rule. But I am not able to arrive at answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain in detail how it is you "tried using  L'Hospital's rule."  On its face this expression is not a ratio, so L'Hospital's rule will not be immediately applicable.  Also, it is not a good practice to create a title that consists entirely of $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @hardmath: we can write it as a ratio with exponential term in the denominator.

Comment: What is $\log x$ for $x<0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$f(x)
=x^{a}e^{|\log x|^{1/2}}
$.
$\ln f(x)
=a\ln x+|\log x|^{1/2}
$.

Let
$x = 1/y$,
so
$y \to \infty$
as
$x \to 0$.

$\ln f(1/y)
=a\ln (1/y)+|\log (1/y)|^{1/2}
=-a\ln (y)+|\log y|^{1/2}
$.

The key is that
$\dfrac{|\log y|^{1/2}}{\ln(y)}
\to 0$
as $y \to \infty$.

Therefore
$\ln f(1/y)
=\ln (y)(-a +\dfrac{|\log y|^{1/2}}{\ln(y)})
$.
Since
$\dfrac{|\log y|^{1/2}}{\ln(y)}
\to 0$
as $y \to \infty$
and $a > 0$,
$-a +\dfrac{|\log y|^{1/2}}{\ln(y)}
\lt -a/2$
for large enough $y$
so that
$\ln f(1/y)
\to -\infty$
so
$f(1/y) \to 0$.

Note that this works
for any exponent
less than $1$,
not just
$\frac12$.

Comment: "Let
$x = 1/y$,
so
$y \to \infty$
as
$x \to 0$." Not so, we need $x\to 0^+.$

Comment: Then $y \to \infty^+$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x) = x^{\alpha} e^{\sqrt{\vert \log x \vert}}$$
Consider 
$$\log f(x) = \alpha \log x + \sqrt{\vert \log x \vert} = \log x (\alpha + \frac{ \sqrt{\vert \log x \vert}}{\log x} )=\log x (\alpha - \frac{ \sqrt{\vert \log x \vert}}{\sqrt{\vert \log x \vert}\sqrt{\vert \log x \vert}} )$$
which is
$$\log f(x) = \log x (\alpha - \frac{ 1}{\sqrt{\vert \log x \vert}} )$$
As $x$ goes to zero $\sqrt{\vert \log x \vert}$ goes to $+ \infty$ hence $\alpha - \frac{ 1}{\sqrt{\vert \log x \vert}}$ goes to $\alpha$. Hence

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\log f(x) =\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \alpha \log x  = -\infty$$
So 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)  = e^{-\infty} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^{-y}\to 0$ as  $y\to \infty$ then

$$\large{x^{\alpha}e^{|\log x|^{1/2}}=e^{-\alpha y}\,e^{\sqrt y}=e^{\sqrt y\,-\,\alpha y}\to 0}$$

indeed

$$\sqrt y-\alpha y=y\left(\frac {\sqrt y}y -\alpha\right)=y\left(\frac 1 {\sqrt y}-\alpha\right) \to -\infty$$